# Ansible adhoc command in sequence

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-ad-hoc

I want to run ansible adhoc command on a list of EC2 instances. I want ansible to run it in sequence but ansible runs them in random. For example:

```
13:42:21 @cnayak ansible :► ansible aws -a "hostname"
ec2 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
ip-172-31-36-255

ec3 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
ip-172-31-45-174

13:42:26 @cnayak ansible :► ansible aws -a "hostname"
ec3 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
ip-172-31-45-174

ec2 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
ip-172-31-36-255
```

Any way to make them run in order?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default ansible runs tasks in parallel. If you want them to be executed serially then you can limit number of workers running at the same time by using "--forks" option.

Adding "--forks 1" to your ansible invocation should run your command sequentially on all hosts (in order defined by inventory).

Comment: ansible aws -a "hostname" -f 1 worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `forks` with adhoc command and `serial: 1` inside the playbook.

On adhoc command:

```
ansible aws -a "hostname" --forks=1
```

Inside the playbook:

```
- hosts: aws
  become: yes
  gather_facts: yes
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - YOUR TASKS HERE
```

Answer (score 2):

--forks=1  hasn't been sorting inventory for me in recent versions of ansible (2.7)

Another approach I find useful is using the "oneline" output callback, so I can use the standard `sort` and `grep` tools on the output:

```
ANSIBLE_LOAD_CALLBACK_PLUGINS=1 \
ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=oneline \
ansible \
  -m debug -a "msg={{ansible_host}}\t{{inventory_hostname}}" \
  | sort \
  | grep -oP '"msg": \K"[^"]*"' \
  | xargs -n 1 echo -e
```

This has been useful for quick-n-dirty reports on arbitrary vars or (oneline) shell command outputs.